# How can setLatestEventInfo be resolved in API 23+

Tags: java, android, notifications, push-notification

I'm creating a mock push notification app.
which take input from user and show a local Push Notification over the device.
as i know `setLatestEventInfo` method is discontinued in new `API (23+)` levels.
i was wondering what could be the possible patch to the code.
below is the code:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
EditText ed1,ed2,ed3;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ed1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
    ed2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    ed3=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    Button b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);

    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String tittle=ed1.getText().toString().trim();
            String subject=ed2.getText().toString().trim();
            String body=ed3.getText().toString().trim();

            NotificationManager notif=(NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            Notification notify=new Notification(R.drawable.icon,tittle,System.currentTimeMillis());
            PendingIntent pending= PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, new Intent(), 0);

            notify.setLatestEventInfo(getApplicationContext(),subject,body,pending); //cannot resolve 'setLatestEventInfo' method 
            notif.notify(0, notify);
        }
    });
}
```

Thank You :)

Comment: Why do you need it? AFAIK, everything that `setLatestEventInfo()` could do is handled by `NotificationCompat.Builder`.

Comment: yes exactly...thanks... but how can i implement it in my code ?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html

Comment: It is getting more complex to understand sir :(

Answer (score 4):

Use `NotificationCompat.Builder`, along with `setSmallIcon()`, `setTicker()`, `setContentTitle()`, `setContentText()`, and `setContentIntent()`.

For example, this method from [this sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Notifications/DownloadNotify) from [this book](https://commonsware.com/Android) uses all of the above:

```
  private void raiseNotification(String mimeType, File output,
                                 Exception e) {
    NotificationCompat.Builder b=new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);

    b.setAutoCancel(true).setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL);

    if (e == null) {
      b.setContentTitle(getString(R.string.download_complete))
       .setContentText(getString(R.string.fun))
       .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.stat_sys_download_done)
       .setTicker(getString(R.string.download_complete));

      Intent outbound=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

      outbound.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(output), mimeType);

      b.setContentIntent(PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, outbound, 0));
    }
    else {
      b.setContentTitle(getString(R.string.exception))
       .setContentText(e.getMessage())
       .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.stat_notify_error)
       .setTicker(getString(R.string.exception));
    }

    NotificationManager mgr=
        (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    mgr.notify(NOTIFY_ID, b.build());
  }
}
```